# How does Facebook's "Also send message as text" interact with SMS message alerts?

Tags: facebook, sms

The new Facebook inbox allows you to a message to also be sent as a text. If the receiver already has SMS message alerts, are two messages received?

Answer (score 1):

When you send a message as a text, the receiver will receive that message in his/her Facebook inbox first and then Facebook will send a notification/message to that user if he/she is using SMS message alert services. So one message will be in that user's Facebook inbox, and one message will be forwarded to him/her by Facebook SMS alert services.